# Params are not passing and navigator is not available in createStackNavigator - React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using `React Navigation` in my App. I created the `createStackNavigator` with `createBottomTabNavigator` in Header I'm trying to access the params that is I'm passing from my screen but these params are not available. And I also want when somebody click on Header button then move on to new screen but problem is that 'navigation.navigator()` function is not available in header buttons.

Here is how my **Nav.js** looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import Screen1 from './Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen2';
import Screen3 from './Screen3';

const bottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    openOrder: Screen1,
    closeOrder: Screen2
  }
);

const mainNav = createStackNavigator({
  order: {
    screen: bottomTab,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerRight: (
        <View>
          <Button title="Map" onPress={() => console.log(navigation)} />
        </View>
      )
    })
  },
  map: Screen3
});

export default createAppContainer(mainNav);
```

**Screen1.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Screen1 = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.navigation.setParams({
      title: 'Some Content',
      map: mapit,
    });
  }, []);

  const mapit = () => {
    console.log('Map it function');
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Screen 1</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Screen1;
```

**Screen2.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const Screen2 = () => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>Screen 2</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default Screen2;
```

**Screen3.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

const Screen3 = () => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>Screen 3</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default Screen3;
```

Here is [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@azeemhaider/238012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem by creating a button that has a navigation function.

`withNavigation` is a higher order component which passes the `navigation` prop into a wrapped component. It's useful when you cannot pass the `navigation` prop into the component directly, or don't want to pass it in case of a deeply nested child.

**Exmaple**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class MyMoveButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        title="map"
        onPress={() => {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("map");
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

// withNavigation returns a component that wraps MyBackButton and passes in the
// navigation prop
export default withNavigation(MyMoveButton);
```

**Usage**

```js
import MyMoveButton from "path for MyMoveButton"
...

headerRight: (
        <View>
          <MyMoveButton />
        </View>
      )
```

Comment: And how can I get `params` ? Because `navigation.getParam()` and `navigation.state.params` is not working

Comment: @AzeemHaider You can use `useRoute`